# Red bars, yellowing, and pixelated output from Premiere

Tags: premiere

I'm having trouble exporting from Premiere (OS X 10.11, Premiere Pro CC 2015.0.2). While the preview plays flawlessly, when I export I get odd red bars, yellowing, and pixelation in some (or all) of the still images. I've attempted many different settings in the output, and while there is some variation on the severity and frequency of the distortion, it is always present.

Here is a sample of the issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are your export parameters? What codec, data rate, etc? Whatever information you can supply will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is extremely well documented in the Adobe Premiere forum.  Premiere Pro is not fully compatible with El Capitan (10.11).  The work-around is to disable the GPU by selecting "Mercury Software Render", which will remind you why so many people hated doing digital video before GPU cards existed.

The situation is a mess.  Adobe has apologized, is working on a fix, and has no idea when Premiere Pro, or an update to 10.11, or both, will result in a working system.

The other work-around is to back-out 10.11 and downgrade to Yosemite.